# updown / alternating permutation by explicit backtracking

Tags: haskell

I got the following solution using the List of Successes for the updown / alternating permutation problem which is working in Hugs 98:

```
updown :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [[a]]
updown []         = [[]]
updown list       = smaller list

bigger :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [[a]]
bigger []         = [[]]
bigger [x]        = [[x]]
bigger list       = [n:p | n <- list,p <- smaller (filter (/=n) list),n < p!!0]

smaller :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [[a]]
smaller []        = [[]]
smaller [x]       = [[x]]
smaller list      = [n:p | n <- list,p <- bigger (filter (/=n) list),n > p!!0]
```

As you can see the function filters out all the non-fitting solutions with LoS. Now I was wondering how to get the same result but by using Explicit Backtracking (build in an accumulating parameter a partial solution; further on in the recursion there will be a solution). I just need a small nudge in the right direction. 
Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, I voted to close this question as "unclear what it's asking". It seems other people don't agree with me enough to vote along, but do agree enough not to try answering. So I'd like to suggest that you take a little while to think about how to make this question more concrete. I think your question will get more attention if you can describe a little bit about what a successful answer would contain and what problem a successful answer would be solving.